# access req.cookie from supertest

Tags: supertest

I set a cookie and I usually access it like this when I need to test a "protected" request.

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  await db.connect();

  //sign my user and get the token
  const response = await request(app).post("/gettoken").send(credentials);
  TOKEN = response.headers["set-cookie"].pop().split(";")[0];
})

//test exemple
  it("exemple", async () => {
    const result = await request(app).post("/path").set(`Cookie`, TOKEN).send(data);
  });
```

So far I had no problem with it but in one of my function that I want to test I have this line:

```js
user = await getUser(req.cookies.token);
```

the function getUser is pretty simple:

```js
  const userToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY);

  user = await User.findOne({ _id: userToken.payload._id });
  return user;
```

Seems like supertest does not work with req.cookies. Is there any way to set "req.cookies.token" during my test ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question but please, be aware that **I have no idea why it works**. Actually I was a bit desperate to not find any solution so I did try something without any hope but, surprisely, it worked.

so basically after restarting docker my console.log were all similars (npm run test vs test with postman)

```js
module.exports.getUser = async (token) => {
  console.log(token);
  console.log(process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY);
  const userToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY);
  console.log(userToken.payload._id);

  const user = await User.find({ _id: userToken.payload._id });
  return user;
};
```

```js
  it("with success", async () => {
    const question = {
      title: "title",
      content: "content",
    };
    const result = await request(app).post("/api/forum/question").set("Cookie", TOKEN).send(question);
    console.log(result.body);
    expect(result.status).toBe(200);
  });
```

And I had this error:

```js
    { error: { message: "Cannot read property '_id' of null" } }
```

I did change

```js
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userToken.payload._id });
```

by

```js
  const user = await User.find({ _id: userToken.payload._id });
```

And now it works as expected.

If someone can explain me why findOne was not working with test (but was ok with postman) I would be happy to understand... because to me, as beginner, it does not make any sense.